# How should we handle questions with download links to code?

Tags: discussion, security, downloads

Regarding this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798125/java-eclipse-programming-need-support

So yeah someone is learning Java and posted his code as a link. He also posted the code in the question, which is a good thing, but I am wondering how SO handles questions with download links? I mean I'm not going to go out of my way to download someone's executable program to help answer his question. Is this considered a security issue? Should we flag/remove the links?

Comment: By simply closing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular question could be closed for a few other reasons... But if the only issue is a suspicious link to download a program/file/whatever you can always just edit the question to remove the link and leave a comment explaining your edit. If you notice a number of suspicious looking links from the same user it may be worth a flag, but in general if its a problem that you can solve without bothering the mods, go for it.

Comment: Obviously with any such edit if the user rolls it back then you'll want to flag a mod rather than getting in an edit war.